# Keyup event not firing when keydown is released after a click outside document

Tags: javascript

When i hold a key down and then click outside my document (not the borwser window, for example clicking on the browser address bar on top of the document) and then releasing my key, the keyup event won't trigger.

```js
var keyIsDown = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  keyIsDown = true;
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  keyIsDown = false;
});

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(keyIsDown);
}, 10);
```

How can i detect that the key is not pressed anymore? I'm aware of `keypress` event but it's deprecated.

Since i'm clicking outside the document, i can assume that no key are being pressed anymore but i can't seem to find an event for this.

And `visibilitychange` event, won't work in this case.

Comment: `visibilitychange` seems like a good fall-back, why is that not an option?

Comment: I think you can't. You could use `mouseleave` for the window as fall-back to check when the cursor is leaving it.

Comment: @DBS no it won't trigger on a click on the address bar. It only trigger on alt tab, minimize...

Comment: @biberman i can't use mouseleave because it's a game and you don't necessary need to have the mouse on top of the document/window in order to play/send keys

Comment: Ah, ok. That means it doesn't work when the document loses the focus. But i don't know if the `blur` event is working for that case. Could you test it?

Comment: I could swear that i tested blur before and it wasn't working, but i was wrong. Thanks @biberman

Comment: Blur is not solving the problem, try holding a key and press mouse right-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like i wrote in the comments the problem is that the window loses the focus and gets "deaf" for events. You could detect that with the `blur` event.

**Working example:** (*i omitted the `setInterval` function because of the infinite console-loop*)

```js
var keyIsDown = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  keyIsDown = true;
  console.log(keyIsDown);
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  keyIsDown = false;
  console.log(keyIsDown);
});

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  keyIsDown = false;
  console.log(keyIsDown);
});

console.log(keyIsDown);
```